# Dehumidifier with power socket to hang on the wall

Tags: garage, socket, cord-and-plug, dehumidifier

Goodmorning everyone! 
I am looking for a dehumidifier to put in the garage that has the following features:

- the plug to be inserted into the socket (unusual as a thing because usually dehumidifiers are merged into the electricity of the house, if I'm not mistaken);
- hangability on the wall;
- drain pipe for water that I can direct where I want or extend it with another tube (for example, I make it converge into a bucket or a manhole)

If someone could send me the link where I can buy it, it would do me a great pleasure. 
I absolutely do not want those who are on the ground with the wheels that look like robots with the inner bucket, or a wall dehumidifier to merge with the garage electrical system. Unfortunately my garage doesn't have an elaborate electrical system.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look more into portable dehumidifiers.  There is something important you are missing.   Also, that thing is called a "shelf"...

Answer (score 1):

All portable dehumidifiers come with a power cord to plug into a wall socket. I do not know of any that can be wall mounted. Some come with 3 options for draining the water; an enclosed plastic basin that you manually dump, an optional hose connection that can have a short hose connected and run to a floor drain and an enclosed pump and tubing that can run many feet to a drain. I bought mine at Lowes or Home Depot. Go on-line or go to a store and read the box.

Comment: I need wall mounted because once in a while the garage with heavy rain can flood, and above all, since the space is small, it is very helpful not to have it on the ground. I'm sorry they closed the question, but I don't see otherwise how I can be helped...

Comment: why not just build a shelf to hold a dehumidifier instead of sitting it on the floor

Comment: It might be a good idea if the dehumidifier didn't have the inner bucket. Can you imagine, every time you take it full of water, empty it and put it back on the shelf? Too expensive in terms of use. If it were fixed on a shelf, and the tube went down to the ground it would still be the optimal solution!

Comment: "Send me the link where I can buy it" is considered a shopping question and is off topic here. Like d.george suggested, you can put a portable unit on a shelf or platform to get it off the floor, then direct the drain where you want it.

Comment: Is really there a portable dehumidifier to which you can direct the flow of outgoing water? This would be already optimal..!